# How can I investigate what other users are currently logged in?

Tags: users, shutdown, session, d-bus

Since the last few days I get an error message when I try to shut my laptop down:

> System policy prevents stopping the system when other users are logged in

This error message includes a prompt for administrator password.

I don't think that there should be other users logged in.

How can I find out what the problem is?

### What I've tried

```
$ w
 08:00:47 up  1:50,  2 users,  load average: 0,74, 0,95, 0,70
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
moose    tty8     :0               07:57    1:49m  4.88s  0.11s x-session-manager
moose    pts/0    :0.0             08:00    2.00s  0.11s  0.00s w


$ loginctl
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
        c1        117 couchdb                          
        c2       1000 moose            seat0
```

2 sessions listed.

I'm not sure: is that already the problem?

`$ sudo shutdown -h now` worked as expected.

### How I shut the computer down

By clicking on `System > Shut Down... > Shut Down`:

[image]

### System information

I have Linux Mint MATE:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pc08 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 16 Petra \n \l
```

Comment: If it's any comfort I had a similar issue with Fedora about an year ago, probably [bug #890827](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=890827). I'm not sure if the same applies to Linux Mint, but what's the output of `loginctl`?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: It seems as if CouchDB might cause this problem. That would make sense, because I've installed CouchDB just some days ago. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: How is the CouchDB server run?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I don't know. How do I find it out? (I've just installed the debian package)

Comment: Then it should be a system service and not cause any trouble at all. Are you sure CouchDB is to blame?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: No.

Answer (score 1):

By searching out I could find this:

Go to

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.consolekit.policy
```

Then you should find out the code that has inside the message tag your message

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users">
  <description>Stop the system when multiple users are logged in</description>
  <message>System policy prevents stopping the system when other users are logged in</message>
<defaults>
  <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Then change the

```
<allow_active> auth_admin_keep </allow_active>
```

to

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

then save and restart.
If you have the same problem with restarting your system, then is the same step but over the restart code.

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart">
```

Comment: I've used this system for many months and did not have this problem. Do you have any idea what could have changed that? How did you find this solution?

Comment: I google it and find it on a blog
http://attecnica.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/system-policy-prevents-restarting-the-system-when-other-users-are-logged-in/

But it only say how to solve it not how it happens